# php creating input hidden field but getting whitespace in value

Tags: php

if i have this code (in which i loop through XML elements):

```
  foreach($headItems->BillOfMaterialItem as $item){
          $count++;
          echo '<div style="display:none;">';
          echo '<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-DESCRIPTION['.$count.']" value="'. $item->PricatLine->ArticleData->SuppliersDescription->Description.'">';
          echo '</div>';
        }
```

which will return me -> `<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-DESCRIPTION[1]" value="PROF DICTAFOON         DVR-720">`

with WHITESPACE Beweetn DICTAFOON and DVR-720,  while in the XML file there is  no whitespaces.

this is the xml where i eventually find my description:

```
-<SuppliersDescription>

<Description>PROF DICTAFOON DVR-720</Description>

</SuppliersDescription>
```

How to fix this? I already tried trim and div display:none

all of which not working

Comment: please share your xml source file and the relevant bit of code where you process it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's just replace all the extra whitespace in your string with a single space.

```
$description = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $item->PricatLine->ArticleData->SuppliersDescription->Description);
echo '<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-DESCRIPTION['.$count.']" value="'. $description.'">';
```

Explanation:
The pattern we provide to `preg_replace`, namely `/\s+/`, means one or more spaces. This basically replaces one or more spaces with a single space character.

Answer (score 0):

try this maybe it will work.

```
echo str_replace(" ","",$item->PricatLine->ArticleData->SuppliersDescription->Description);
```

or trim($item->PricatLine->ArticleData->SuppliersDescription->Description);